# Javascript Remoting - sending sObject as argument

Tags: javascript-remoting

This question appears to have been answered several times on here, but none of the solutions are working for me.  I have an Apex function defined like so:

```
@RemoteAction
global static ActivityWrapper createActivity(Activity__c activity)
```

And when I call this Javascript function:

```
Controller.createActivity(
    {ForWeek__c: "2014-04-21T08:00:00.000Z",
     Notes__c: "sdfsdf",
     Type__c: "Referral",
     Id: null,
     sObjectType: "Activity__c"}, callback);
```

I always get back this error message:

```
Visualforce Remoting Exception: Unexpected type for Controller.createActivity(Activity__c)
```

As far as I know this is all that is required, but I can't get past this.

Comment: Is it possible that activity is a reserved keyword?

Comment: Can you confirm that you have no namespace defined in the org?

Comment: @greenstork even if Activity were a reserved keyword, Activity__c would not be, correct?

Comment: @KeithC I just confirmed that there is no namespace defined in my org.  I'm just using a simple Developer instance at this point anyway.

Comment: Activity is a custom sObject and would be okay, it's your variable name that you've chosen that may be reserved.

Comment: @greenstork it looks like `activate` is reserved, but `activity` is not. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_reserved_words.htm

Comment: I tried: `{!$RemoteAction.remote.createAccount}({ Id: null, Name: "Nobody", Industry: "Technology" }, function(d,e) { console.log(d.Id); });` in my dev org. It works. The sObjectType param is only required if you're using generics (SObject). Try not including the type. Also check the case sensitivity of those field names.

Comment: Post that as an answer @sfdcfox, sounds legit to me.

Comment: @sfdcfox that may work, but because of what I'm doing I need to act against the global controller object.

Comment: It's actually looking like RemoteTK might do exactly what I need to do.  I don't know what that one is hidden along side forcetk instead of on its own. I wouldn't expect to find such a thing in the "REST" toolkit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT 2:**

I've also just noticed that you're passing a formatted date string, with Visualforce Remoting you need to pass your Date values as Unix timestamp values (in milliseconds, rather than seconds).

So for your example you need to pass `1398067200000`.

---

**EDIT:**

In fact, I've just noticed that your JSON is poorly formed, you are missing a few commas (after the `ForWeek__c`, `Notes__c` and `Type__c` values). Try this:

```
Controller.createActivity
(
    {
        ForWeek__c: "1398067200000",
        Notes__c: "sdfsdf",
        Type__c: "Referral",
        Id: null
    }, 
    callback
);
```

---

I've tried replicating your issue and I've not managed to end up with exactly the same error message, however I have stripped it down to the simplest example.

The only solution I can offer you is to try and pull your controller and page back to it's simplest possible version (i.e. something that looks like the below) and build from there, because other than setting the `sObjectType` field I can't see anything wrong with what you're doing.

**RemotingSObject__c**

- Field__c (String)

**RemotingSObjectController**

```
public class RemotingSObjectController
{
    @RemoteAction
    public static RemotingSObject__c getRemoteObject() 
    {
        RemotingSObject__c anObject = new RemotingSObject__c(Field__c = 'Value');
        return anObject;
    }

    @RemoteAction
    public static String setRemoteObject(RemotingSObject__c anObject) 
    {
        return anObject.Field__c;
    }
}
```

**RemoteObjectPage**

```
<apex:page controller="RemotingSObjectController">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var sobject;

        function getRemoteObject() 
        {
            RemotingSObjectController.getRemoteObject
            ( 
                function(result, event)
                {
                    if (event.status) 
                    {
                        console.log(result);
                    } 
                    else if (event.type === 'exception') 
                    {
                        console.log(event.message);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        console.log(event.message);
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        function setRemoteObject() 
        {
            RemotingSObjectController.setRemoteObject
            (
                {Field__c: 'Success!'},
                function(result, event)
                {
                    if (event.status) 
                    {
                        console.log(result);
                    } 
                    else if (event.type === 'exception') 
                    {
                        console.log(event.message);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        console.log(event.message);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    </script>

    <input type="button" onclick="getRemoteObject();" value="get"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="setRemoteObject();" value="set"/>

</apex:page>
```

**Result**

Clicking the `get` button results in a JSON representation of my `RemotingSObject__c` in my Javascript log with `'Value'` in `Field__c`, clicking the `set` button results in `'Success!'` being printed to my Javascript log.

Comment: The example JSON I provided was missing commas, but that was a result of me copying out of the console.  The actual code does the right thing in that respect.  I wonder if my date format doesn't deserialize on the controller side...

Comment: @MattBaker Not sure how I missed that first time through, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

While Alex's response hits the root cause of my original question, I'm glad this confusion arose.  **Do not do what I did accessing the window scoped Controller helper unless you want to reinvent the wheel**.  If you need to use Javascript Remoting for non-CRUD purposes use the "official" method raised by @sfdcfox

```
{!$RemoteAction.remote.createAccount}({ Id: null, Name: "Nobody", Industry: "Technology" }, function(d,e) { console.log(d.Id); });
```

If Remoting is only a means to get at CRUD (like my case) I recommend using the RemoteTK component + controller available here:

https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit/blob/master/RemoteTK.component

As a huge plus, this also allows you infinite CRUD without worrying about API limits.  It should really not be hidden alongside the `forcetk` library though.  I completely overlooked it when I originally pulled in ForceTK.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you suggest not using the scoped controller helper, as it and `Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction` are the documented way of invoking remoting calls rather than the method proposed by sfdcfox. I'd also recommend the AJAX Toolkit as an alternative if you're planning on doing purely CRUD operations as it doesn't require you to use a specific controller.

Comment: @AlexTennant good to know.  I just recommended against it since using the global helper forces you to manually handle things like date values on the way out of your application.  If you can avoid it, do so.  As far as the AJAX toolkit, I'm not doing much by way of true Visualforce pages, but instead am using Ember.js and Ember Data. I wrote an Ember Data adapter around forcetk.js and remotetk.js, which is what lead to this question.  Hopefully I can get the adapter stable enough to release soon, since Ember lacks an official Mobile Toolkit for SalesForce.

Comment: That all makes sense. Good to know.